# Iterate over Pandas dataframe to plot time series intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe with a bunch of info, but I want to plot a series of graphs (like boxplots and cumulative density functions) for six-months intervals iterating over the months like: a plot for the first six months starting from the oldest one (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun), then a plot for another six months starting from the second oldest one (feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul) and then (mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug) etc.

I tried a probably very naive way trying to iterating with loops:

```
months = df_filt['time'].unique()
```

which outputs this:

[image]

And then:

```
j = 0
k = 0

while j < len(months) - 5:
    while k < 6:
        dff = df_filt.loc[df_filt['time'] == months[k]]
        dff = pd.concat(dff)
        k += 1

    sns.histplot(data=df_filt,
                 x='hrs_prev',
                 hue='Faltou',
                 bins=len(df_filt),
                 stat="density",
                 element="step",
                 fill=False,
                 cumulative=True,
                 common_norm=False)
    plt.title("Cumulative distribution function")
    plt.show()

    k = 0
```

This is obviously wrong, cause when `k=0` at the end of the loops I would plot the same thing over and over. I can change the `while k < 6` to another thing because loops always does the job, but they are never the most optimal way of doing the jobs....

I can try something like
while k < j+5:
....
k = k-5

and it would work, because j would be incremented in the right way at the end of the loop.
It seems to work, but I heard that pandas has some built-in function that does the job with lags for time series, or something called `ThreadPoolExecutor` but I didn't seem to find examples that could help me.

So, my question is:

Are there any optimal way of doing this with some built-in function that deals with time series and that can plot my data separating the intervals in the way I need it to? This `ThreadPoolExecutor` is the right way of doing this? Or I would have to do it by hand?

Any help would be of great thanks and would really save me a huge time

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it is not the best solution, but it works fine:

```
months = df_filt['time'].unique()

j = 0
k = 0
df_plot = pd.DataFrame()

while j < len(months) - 5:
    while k < j+6:
    dff = df_filt.loc[df_filt['time'] == months[k]]
    df_plot = pd.concat([df_plot, dff])
    k += 1

print(df_plot)
print(df_plot['time'].value_counts())
df_plot = pd.DataFrame()
print(k)
print(j)
k -= 5
j += 1
```

I wanted something more elegant and optimal, 'cause I do not like loops. But it does the job for a while.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that is just a loop I created. IT does the job